# how many people received 4 drugs of interest? R

Tags: r, unique, long-integer

I have a long list of people receiving drugs coded in the variable ATC. I want to find out how many people have used 4 specific drugs. For example, I want to count how many people have used this particular pattern of drugs "C07ABC" & "C09XYZ" &"C08123" &"C03ZOO". Some people may have used some agents (eg C07 or C08) more than once, thats ok, I just want to count how many unique people had the regimen I'm interested in. I don't care how many times they had the unique drugs. However, because I have various patterns that I want to look up - I would like to use the grepl function. To explain this further, my first attempt at this problem tried a sum command:

```
sum(df[grepl('^C07.*?'|'^C09.*?'|'^C08.*?|C03.*?', as.character(df$atc)),])
```

However this doesn't work because I think the sum command needs a boolean function. ALso, I think the | sign isn't correct here either (I want an &) but I'm just showing the code so that you know what I'm after. Maybe an ave function is what I need - but am unsure of how I would code this?

Thanks in advance.

```
df
   names  fruit      dates     atc
4   john   kiwi 2010-07-01  C07ABC
7   john  apple 2010-09-01  C09XYZ
9   john banana 2010-11-01  C08123
13  john orange 2010-12-01  C03ZOO
14  john  apple 2011-01-01  C07ABC
2   mary orange 2010-05-01  C09123
5   mary  apple 2010-07-01  C03QRT
8   mary orange 2010-07-01  C09ZOO
10  mary  apple 2010-09-01  C03123
12  mary  apple 2010-11-01  C09123
1    tom  apple 2010-02-01  C03897
3    tom banana 2010-03-01 C02CAMN
6    tom  apple 2010-06-01  C07123
11   tom   kiwi 2010-08-01 C02DA12
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you should have just passed the grepl to `sum`.

Comment: I just put the ^ in out of habit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to not needing to deliver entire dataframe lines to `sum` you also had extra quote marks in that pattern:

```
> sum( grepl('^C07.*|^C09.*|^C08.*|C03.*', df$atc) )
[1] 12
```

I think this is easier to read:

```
>  sum( grepl('^(C07|C09|C08|C03).*', df$atc) )
[1] 12
```

But now I read that you want all of thos used and to do the calculation within a patient id. That might have requiree using & as the connector but I decide to try a different route and use `unique` and then count then number of unique matches while doing it within an `aggregate` operation.

```
> aggregate(atc ~ names, data=df, 
                       function(drgs) length(unique(grep('^(C07|C09|C08|C03)', drgs))))
  names atc
1  john   5
2  mary   5
3   tom   2
```

Although that's the number of matching items but not the number of unique items, because I forgot to put value=TRUE in the `grep` call (and also need to use `substr` to avoid separately counting congeners with different trailing ATC codes):

```
> aggregate(atc ~ names, data=df, function(drgs) length(unique(grep('^C0[7983]', substr(drgs,1,3), value=TRUE))))
  names atc
1  john   4
2  mary   2
3   tom   2
```

This would be somewhat similar to @MichaelLawrence's matrix/table approach, but I think it would scale better since the "tables" being created would be much smaller:

```
 combo <- c("C07", "C09", "C08", "C03")
 tapply(df$atc, df$names, function(drgs) sum(combo %in% substr(drgs,1,3)) )
#------
john mary  tom 
   4    2    2
```

Comment: or even `'^C0[3789]'`

Comment: this is great - thanksf or the code. I don't understand the [7983] bit though. What is it doing? and why has ben suggested a different number?

Comment: Different? ... than what? The "[7983]" is a character class which would match any one of those items inside the square-brackets.

Comment: It will match `CO` at the beginning of the string and any number out of `3789` that will follow it.

Comment: Oh, I see the point of your question now .... since you are matching any one of those items, the order in which they are entered is immaterial. Any permutation of the four digits would be equivalent in a character class.

Comment: Ping! Penny just dropped. Thanks you guys for this. Learning loads tonight.

Comment: I think you  could do the `substring` part outside the actually `tapply` process as in `with(df, tapply(substr(atc, 1, 3), names, function(drgs) sum(combo %in% drgs)))` in order speed things up.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider avoiding the use of regular expressions, and instead derive some set of meaningful columns from column `atc`. For combinations, you probably want a 2-way table of person and drug, and then compute on the matrix to count combinations.

For example:

```
tab <- xtabs(~ names + atc, df)
combo <- c("C07ABC", "C09XYZ", "C08123", "C03ZOO")
haveCombo <- rowSums(tab[,combo] > 0) == length(combo)
sum(haveCombo)
```

The last two lines could easily be turned into a function for each combination.

EDIT: This approach can be applied to other, derived columns, so if you're interested in the prefix then,

```
df$agent <- substring(df$atc, 1, 3)
tab <- xtabs(~ names + agent, df)
combo <- c("C07", "C09", "C08", "C03")
```

and proceed as before.

Comment: Great - thanks for this. This is definitely something I can use, although might be a bit tedious as the reason I wanted grepl is because the umbrella code c07 (or C08 or c09) actually contains multiple sub codes that I need to search for too. In other words, I need to search for all drugs that start with C08 (or C07 or whatever). I was hoping the grepl would be an efficient way to do this. Nonetheless, your answer is still super handy and I guess I can just type out all the codes! Thank you.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how you could generalize it, in a way that is more formal than regexps.

Comment: I was just going to propose that edit, you probably will also have to update `combo` to something like `combo <- c("C07","C09", "C08", "C03")`

Comment: Briliant! Thats great! I actually didn't know the substring code. Am familar with it in excel - but great to do it in R. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael, that could be a fairly large matrix you create with xtabs. Dimensions are going to be unique(names) times unique(atc).  I might worry that it won't scale very well.

Comment: Then pass `sparse=TRUE` to `xtabs()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
drugs <- c("C07ABC","C09XYZ", "C08123", "C03ZOO")
table(unique(df[df$atc %in% drugs, c("names", "atc")])$names)
# john mary  tom 
#   4    0    0 
names(which(table(unique(df[df$atc %in% drugs, c("names", "atc")])$names) > 3))
# [1] "john"
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(names = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("john", "mary", "tom"
), class = "factor"), fruit = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("apple", "banana", 
"kiwi", "orange"), class = "factor"), dates = structure(c(5L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("2010-02-01", 
"2010-03-01", "2010-05-01", "2010-06-01", "2010-07-01", "2010-08-01", 
"2010-09-01", "2010-11-01", "2010-12-01", "2011-01-01"), class = "factor"), 
    atc = structure(c(8L, 11L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 5L, 12L, 3L, 
    10L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("C02CAMN", "C02DA12", "C03123", 
    "C03897", "C03QRT", "C03ZOO", "C07123", "C07ABC", "C08123", 
    "C09123", "C09XYZ", "C09ZOO"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("names", 
"fruit", "dates", "atc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("4", 
"7", "9", "13", "14", "2", "5", "8", "10", "12", "1", "3", "6", 
"11"))
```

Comment: That actually will give misleading results for `drugs <- c("C07","C09", "C08", "C03")` and `df$atc <- substring(df$atc, 1, 3)`. `%in%` will match *any* occurrence in `drugs`, thus, even if `mary` had five times only `C0` (like she actually does), it will always return 5 times `TRUE` and `mary` will pass the test.

Comment: Calling `unique` on the data frame is not what you want, because e.g. the fruits get in the way.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a continuation of @Michael Lawrence's answer.  I changed the drugs to what @user2363642 wanted, and I also substringed the atc column to only use the three first characters, which again, I believe is what @user2363642 wanted.  Also, for the rowSums, I first changed all non-zero quantities to 1, to ensure we don't double count drugs.

```
drugs <- c("C07", "C09", "C08", "C03")
df$atc.abbr <- substring(df$atc, 1, 3)

xt <- xtabs(~ names + atc.abbr, df)
xt[xt>0] <- 1
rowSums(xt[,drugs]) >= length(drugs)
```

Output:

```
 john  mary   tom 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: The `> 0` in my answer avoided the double counting.